# Editing a custom infopath form published to a library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-form, custom-list

I had built an infopath form and published it to a library in sharepoint.

Unfotunately, I lost the file on my local machine in the middle of a user profile sync chaos.

I tried editing the form in Infopath from sharepoint, but it would not let me go ahead with it.

Is there a way I can find the original file on the sharepoint server (Does sharepoint store a copy of the file when published?). I am open to anything that will help me find this file given the 3-4 hours I put into it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:
[Another answer by Chris](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43972/8319) gives better variant.

---

Navigate in your browser to a list in quesion > on ribbon press "**Customize Form**" button (under  **List Tools** > **List** tab > **Customize List**).
This will open customized before by you **Sharepoint List Form** in Infopath Designer 2010 which you can save wherever you want.

Though, from your wording of actions (which are usually vice versa), I am afraid that by custom list you call something else like library. To find the most recent Infopath template published to library navigate to a library in browser > on ribbon click **Library settings** button > **Advanced settings** > the **Document template** textbox will show you a relative to your site path, by default:

- **NameOfLibrary/Forms/template.xsn**

if you have not customized this location.

Though, if you changed published your Infopath XSN form template many times, then the old Infopath XML forms will be referenced by href in heading of saved in library Infopath forms .XML files... if you have not relinked those files to the most recently published Infopath .XSN forma template.

Update:
For example, if URL of my (form) library is:

- _https://gennadyvanin.sharepoint.com/Web1/FormLibEmployeeCAML
  it is opened on navigation as
  _https://gennadyvanin.sharepoint.com/Web1/FormLibEmployeeCAML/Forms/AllItems.axpx

then

- _https://gennadyvanin.sharepoint.com/Web1/FormLibEmployeeCAML/Forms/template.xsn

should start download dialogue of that template.  It can "fail" on 1st attempt, just try once more.

Or, better (since it is not rigid location), in Sharepoint Designer 2010, on ribbon, File > Sites > **Open Site** (subsite) > expand **All Files** > **NameOfLibrary**  > Forms > right-click **template.xsn** (if it was not changed) > Open with > Microsoft Infopath Designer 2010, amongst other options.

It should contain embedded resource files or references to network/sharepoint site path locations.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed and published the form a couple of times from my desktop before I lost it and Yes you are right, I was referring to a library and not a custom list. I do have a couple of files that were included in the infopath file. Would that be part of the template as well?

Comment: I cant seem to open the template in design view either. How do I go about editing it?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it (if "Open with Explorer" works for you)

In the form library, on the ribbon navigate under "Library Tools" to the "Library" tab. In the "Connect & Export" section find "Open with Explorer". Depending on your screen resolution the full label may not be displayed; the icon looks like a folder with an arrow pointing to a computer monitor.

When the library has opened in Windows Explorer find the "Forms" folder. In that folder should be an InfoPath template titled "Template.xsn". Download that template and design it.

Comment: Thanks Chris! It look like infopath wouldnt let me edit the original template. I am able to open in design mode once I saved it to my desktop ;)

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it working :)

Comment: Of course you cannot edit, it is used/bound/in-work by sharepoint. Instead of double-clicking, right-click on found there xxxxx.xsn (template.xsn) > Design which will open it in your local (on your machine) Infopath Designer 2010 from where you can save it locally or do whatever you want