# Edit Library Form

Tags: 2010, infopath, library

Using SP2010: I added a column within the library so that I could display through different views. I can change the value stored in this column through using Library Tools -> Library -> Datasheet View. What I would like to do is to edit the form which appears when the user clicks on the "Add document" (green "+" sign) so users can change this when depositing a document. This would be easily done with a list, but I don't see the same option to edit the form in the library.

I looked at this URL: [Editing a custom infopath form published to a library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43956/editing-a-custom-infopath-form-published-to-a-library) but it doesn't help much because I'm not seeing any of the options it talks about. I do not find a "template.xsn" file in SPD under forms, just DispForm, EditForm, & Upload (all .aspx files).

Do I need to create a template.xsn file? If so, how do I go about doing so? Is there an easy (or easier) way to do this I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: When you add a new column to a document library, that field will appear in the file properties dialog by default. After you select a document with the Upload Document dialog, browse to a file and hit OK, the properties dialog will show.  What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: OMGoodness ... NVM! I had tried to load a document before, but never went past the initial popup for loading the document. After you select the document and move onto the next popup, it has the selection there for the column ... I'm feeling like a dummy. Thanks for your input, teylyn.

Comment: I'll post this as an answer, then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new column to a document library, that field will appear in the file properties dialog by default. After you select a document with the Upload Document dialog, browse to a file and hit OK, the properties dialog will show.

Comment: You are correct, but I (stupidly) answered my own question.